# Font path rendering with SVG

Tags: unicode, path, svg, character, svg-font

I am trying to Render the Character "ٹ" according to my Font Style but it is not working. It is rendering the default font, not mine. Is there anything I am missing? Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg width="500" height="300"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
>
<style type="text/css">
<![CDATA[
.FontFirstSVGFont{font-family:'UrduMe';}
]]>
</style>

<defs>
<font>
<font-face font-family="UrduMe"/>
<glyph unicode="ٹ">
<path
       style="fill:#000000;display:inline"
       id="path2998-7"
       d="m 248.80153,132.52792 c 0.46657,1.42688 0.86292,2.86169 1.10703,4.34417 0.21353,1.48506 0.24006,2.98718 0.25784,4.48467 0.11018,1.53762 -0.35352,2.9685 -1.0374,4.3219 -0.62849,1.26291 -1.7467,2.13138 -2.79106,3.03163 -3.45764,2.48125 -7.51307,4.50988 -11.09046,6.47621 -0.17847,0.0981 -0.40332,0.0718 -0.59377,0.14388 -0.17196,0.0651 -0.32277,0.17624 -0.48416,0.26437 -3.57755,1.4532 -0.77971,0.34289 8.12117,-4.70226 0.15165,-0.086 -0.29818,0.18065 -0.44778,0.27014 -0.5096,0.30482 -1.00878,0.62432 -1.51903,0.92808 -3.63536,2.85541 -7.96723,4.60704 -11.89092,7.04128 -0.68242,0.44521 -1.509,0.3911 -2.25848,0.58876 -0.36196,0.0955 -0.69559,0.27788 -1.05034,0.39735 -1.18947,0.13829 -2.27649,0.56323 -3.42916,0.84582 -1.29616,0.25558 -2.62208,0.27738 -3.93841,0.30174 -1.25342,0.064 -2.46043,0.45152 -3.71879,0.58898 -1.3722,0.11971 -2.75088,0.12419 -4.12722,0.13161 -1.42834,0.003 -2.85668,-4.6e-4 -4.28502,-0.002 -1.42941,-0.002 -2.85882,-0.002 -4.28823,-0.002 -1.42863,-1.6e-4 -2.85726,-1.2e-4 -4.28589,-1.1e-4 -1.42856,2e-5 -2.85712,3e-5 -4.28568,3e-5 -1.42857,1e-5 -2.85714,1e-5 -4.28571,1e-5 -1.42858,0 -2.85715,0 -4.28572,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85714,0 -4.28571,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85715,0 -4.28572,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85714,0 -4.28571,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85714,0 -4.28572,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85714,0 -4.28571,0 -1.42857,0 -2.85714,0 -4.28571,0 -1.42858,0 -2.85715,0 -4.28572,0 -1.41237,0.0473 -2.77618,0.0373 -4.15305,-0.27943 -1.06526,-0.36707 -2.25827,-0.66819 -3.28149,-1.14728 -1.2846,-0.36239 -2.07933,-0.96272 -2.6568,-2.17411 -0.5636,-1.35683 -0.32478,-2.62017 0.172,-3.93834 0.3759,-1.26602 0.95058,-2.43099 1.71603,-3.50322 3.04415,-3.71883 7.69107,-5.88367 12.17848,-7.47721 0.22748,-0.0598 0.45495,-0.11958 0.68243,-0.17938 l -2.9715,3.59976 0,0 c -0.21155,0.0816 -0.63464,0.24478 -0.63464,0.24478 -3.34997,1.56272 -12.72241,7.08308 1.91183,-1.51996 0.17645,-0.10372 -0.3694,0.17989 -0.53802,0.2959 -0.46285,0.31844 -0.5614,0.49932 -0.92158,0.93184 -0.89958,0.8502 -1.51428,1.96779 -1.85321,3.15349 -0.40227,1.09422 -1.02063,1.99027 -0.53466,3.18536 0.42747,0.96036 1.31012,1.14817 2.23928,1.50124 1.04412,0.35302 2.06732,0.79011 3.15441,0.98825 1.32691,0.21652 2.6721,0.10137 4.01162,0.12735 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,0 1.42858,0 2.85715,0 4.28572,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,0 1.42857,0 2.85715,0 4.28572,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28572,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,0 1.42857,0 2.85714,0 4.28571,-1e-5 1.42856,-1e-5 2.85712,-2e-5 4.28568,-3e-5 1.42867,1e-5 2.85734,-1e-5 4.28601,3.5e-4 1.42956,4.7e-4 2.85912,0.001 4.28868,0.003 1.4264,0.002 2.85287,0.006 4.27921,-0.009 1.35694,-0.0226 2.7185,-0.0499 4.06344,-0.24918 1.2535,-0.20898 2.4891,-0.54937 3.77254,-0.49116 1.28307,-0.0581 2.57541,-0.13981 3.81153,-0.51839 1.12568,-0.34384 2.28448,-0.51586 3.40261,-0.88607 1.08435,-0.33852 2.2301,-0.48909 3.20329,-1.12841 3.55497,-1.53796 0.23861,-0.12655 -8.04875,4.73494 -0.15798,0.0927 0.34089,-0.13726 0.49967,-0.22853 0.72845,-0.41873 0.19741,-0.20223 0.87007,-0.73548 0.15359,-0.12176 0.33292,-0.20695 0.49938,-0.31042 0.58058,-0.49053 1.25751,-0.88993 1.91941,-1.26865 3.17736,-1.81803 6.34646,-3.6506 9.53303,-5.45244 0.15967,-0.0903 0.33552,-0.14838 0.50328,-0.22258 3.36197,-1.18169 7.98338,-4.47388 -7.48222,4.5222 -1.22952,0.71519 2.57237,-1.68067 1.57187,-0.92605 1.08044,-0.75498 2.09708,-1.62578 2.96877,-2.61974 0.66343,-1.21211 1.39377,-2.41446 1.27302,-3.85933 -0.007,-1.45351 -0.0117,-2.91101 -0.17721,-4.35708 -0.20466,-1.46774 -0.54097,-2.90613 -1.15962,-4.261 l 9.35095,-4.99945 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       sodipodi:nodetypes="ccccccccccccccccccccssssssssssccccccccccccsccccccsssssssssccscccccccsscsccsccccccc" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000"
       id="path4565"
       d="m 197.46353,125.32287 c -0.0449,0.72849 -0.0359,1.45912 -0.0351,2.18861 8.1e-4,0.7445 0.003,1.489 0.004,2.2335 7.5e-4,0.71647 8e-4,1.43293 8.1e-4,2.1494 10e-6,0.71446 0,1.42891 -1e-5,2.14337 -2e-5,0.71478 -2e-5,1.42955 -2e-5,2.14431 0,0.71483 0,1.42965 0,2.14446 0,0.71483 0,1.42965 0,2.14448 0,0.59567 0,1.19135 0,1.78704 0,0 -4.76702,2.37697 -4.76702,2.37697 l 0,0 c 0,-0.59568 0,-1.19137 0,-1.78704 0,-0.71483 0,-1.42965 0,-2.14446 0,-0.71482 0,-1.42965 0,-2.14447 0,-0.71477 0,-1.42954 -3e-5,-2.14429 0,-0.71446 -1e-5,-1.42891 0,-2.14337 3e-5,-0.71675 8e-5,-1.43348 8e-4,-2.15023 8.1e-4,-0.746 0.003,-1.49202 0.004,-2.23802 7.7e-4,-0.7178 0.01,-1.43688 -0.0351,-2.15359 0,0 4.82657,-2.40667 4.82657,-2.40667 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
    <path
       style="fill:#000000"
       id="path4567"
       d="m 192.28689,143.76975 c 0.14887,-0.64006 0.40618,-1.23426 0.73307,-1.80422 1.29718,-1.89354 3.63047,-2.41626 5.65441,-3.63337 1.41757,-0.85248 -2.88458,1.62361 -4.32689,2.43541 0.24825,-0.15527 0.28643,-0.18283 0.54654,-0.33003 16.27015,-9.2076 -2.96612,1.64562 0.83073,-0.50333 1.62104,-0.91746 3.2491,-1.82298 4.87362,-2.73448 0.65472,-0.20946 1.34915,-0.22057 2.03117,-0.23586 0.72867,-0.008 1.45741,-0.003 2.18607,4.3e-4 0.8016,0.0865 1.12479,0.67388 1.29824,1.37185 0.11743,0.70087 0.10165,1.4145 0.0993,2.12235 -0.0208,0.44148 0.0628,1.22872 -0.42002,1.50401 -1.61453,0.92061 -3.25995,1.78833 -4.88994,2.6825 -0.41563,0.0392 -0.84291,0.0516 -1.23356,0.21618 -0.16774,0.0706 -0.3136,0.18397 -0.47725,0.26324 -0.59703,0.22689 -1.2437,0.24916 -1.87597,0.27429 -0.72282,0.0191 -1.44601,0.0143 -2.16899,0.0127 -0.73172,-0.003 -1.46344,-0.003 -2.19515,-0.004 -0.73065,-4.5e-4 -1.46129,-4.4e-4 -2.19193,-4.4e-4 -0.73042,0 -1.46086,2e-5 -2.1913,3e-5 -0.73043,2e-5 -1.46087,2e-5 -2.1913,2e-5 -0.51497,0.10671 -1.01378,0.27338 -1.44405,0.57212 0,0 4.18095,-3.29452 4.18095,-3.29452 l 0,0 c 0.51216,-0.1987 1.03035,-0.37936 1.59146,-0.35509 0.73043,0 1.46088,-2e-5 2.19131,-2e-5 0.73043,-1e-5 1.46087,-4e-5 2.19132,0 0.7307,6e-5 1.46142,1.5e-4 2.19212,9.4e-4 0.73171,9.3e-4 1.46342,0.003 2.19513,0.004 0.71803,-4.3e-4 1.43706,0.003 2.15375,-0.046 0.61486,-0.0573 1.22359,-0.15077 1.77536,-0.44114 0.55837,-0.23608 1.1622,-0.25117 1.73097,-0.44922 -1.45279,0.82783 -2.91678,1.63711 -4.35835,2.4835 -0.0748,0.0439 0.17109,-0.0375 0.25078,-0.0718 0.40783,-0.17594 0.43554,-0.59131 0.4171,-0.97615 0.003,-0.66978 0.0199,-1.34319 -0.0628,-2.0094 -0.10662,-0.53573 -0.29244,-0.80195 -0.89653,-0.7837 -0.72485,-0.001 -1.45021,-0.008 -2.1746,0.0219 -0.65493,0.0415 -1.31901,0.10063 -1.90197,0.42407 1.43921,-0.81825 2.87768,-1.63777 4.31766,-2.45474 0.0913,-0.0518 -0.18056,0.107 -0.27155,0.15921 -1.61679,0.92857 -3.26603,1.80485 -4.85178,2.78331 -1.39822,0.86273 2.85566,-1.62998 4.28882,-2.43595 0.18356,-0.10317 -0.68637,0.44237 -0.54328,0.32207 -1.61745,0.92267 -3.23186,1.85048 -4.85237,2.768 -1.43853,0.8145 2.86947,-1.6418 4.30646,-2.4589 0.57215,-0.32534 -0.56978,0.31771 -0.69113,0.45724 -0.0646,0.0743 -0.11123,0.16212 -0.16678,0.24317 -0.39913,0.44448 -0.68838,1.02487 -0.77529,1.61075 0,0 -4.88364,2.28944 -4.88364,2.28944 z"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0" />
</glyph>

</font>
</defs>

<text x="100" y="100" class="FontFirstSVGFont">
ٹ
</text>

</svg>
```

If I draw the paths within `<glyph>`, then the font is created successfully but when I attach to the unicode "ٹ" it is not rendered...

Comment: i tried with many other NCR like decimal &#1657; but still no use :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opera, Webkit and Batik (to name a few) have support for the SVG Tiny 1.2 subset of svgfonts, which allow you to specify a `'d'` attribute on the `<glyph>` element for defining the glyph. It's similar to a single path element.

In your example you could concatenate the `'d'` attributes of the three `<path>` elements into a string, and set that as `'d'` on the `<glyph>` element. That should work.

Comment: concatenation not working :-S i am actually dynamically generating that SVG from PHP code i made a Variable $pathe and concatenated then but not working its giving error can you please tell me the way to concatenate that ? please it will be nice

Comment: Tested in Opera 10.6 and it works fine, but see the comment below for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931944/why-svg-is-not-rendering-the-font-path-i-defined/3932973#3932973